# Gradle Cache Dependencies for Docker File

Tags: java, spring, docker, gradle

I have the following dockerfile:

```
ARG SERVICE_NAME=users-service
FROM openjdk:21-ea-slim AS JDK

ARG SERVICE_NAME

WORKDIR /app/${SERVICE_NAME}

COPY ./build.gradle.kts /app
COPY ./${SERVICE_NAME} .

COPY ./${SERVICE_NAME}/gradle ./gradle
COPY ./${SERVICE_NAME}/gradlew .
COPY ./${SERVICE_NAME}/build.gradle.kts .

RUN ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build -x test -build-cache --parallel

COPY ./${SERVICE_NAME}/src ./src

RUN ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build -x test

FROM openjdk:21-ea-slim

ARG SERVICE_NAME

WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir ./logs

COPY --from=JDK /app/${SERVICE_NAME}/build/libs/users-service-0.1.0-alpha-1.jar .

ENV PORT=8001

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "users-service-0.1.0-alpha-1.jar"]
```

[Tree Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT2Tw.png)

But always download the dependecies and spent much time

Try to cache de build gradle with the dependencies

Of course the problem is that when I run the dockerfile it takes a long time because the dependencies are downloaded every time I run it I want to cache the dependencies and from that the new jar is generated and also to skip the tests, because it takes me more than 3 min to build the image and the container so when I make changes and it takes a long time I am learning docker but I have had this inconvenient.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course the problem is that when I run the dockerfile it takes a long time because the dependencies are downloaded every time I run it I want to cache the dependencies and from that the new jar is generated and also to skip the tests, because it takes me more than 3 min to build the image and the container so when I make changes and it takes a long time I am learning docker but I have had this inconvenient.